# MySQL: Grouping results

Tags: mysql, group-by

How can I group my results in a query such as this:

```
SELECT (
             SELECT SUM(wky) FROM table
             WHERE Earnings_Date BETWEEN '2011-08-14' AND '2011-08-16'
            ) +
            (SELECT SUM(earnings) FROM table
            WHERE Earnings_Date BETWEEN '2011-08-14' AND '2011-08-16') / .75
```

The above query returns wky+(earnings/.75) for all the sites (each site has a wky and earnings number for different dates. Where would I put a group by in the above query? I would like my results to be grouped by site_id, since the above query just returns the sum of the earnings of all of them.

Thanks!

Comment: A bit hard without seeing the actual rows fetched by the query, but what happens if you add a GROUP BY on the outermost select, at the end of the query?

Comment: i get a mysql error: 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT site_id, (SUM(wky) + (SUM(earnings) / 0.75)) 
FROM Earnings_Date
WHERE Earnings_Date BETWEEN '2011-08-14' AND '2011-08-16'
GROUP BY site_id
```

Your data comes from the same table for both queries, so you can combine them.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (
         SELECT SUM(wky) FROM table
         WHERE Earnings_Date BETWEEN '2011-08-14' AND '2011-08-16'
        ) +
        (SELECT SUM(earnings) FROM table
        WHERE Earnings_Date BETWEEN '2011-08-14' AND '2011-08-16') / .75

, site_id GROUP BY site_id
```

:)

Comment: @cularis if you can't determine it yourself, than what difference it is for you? :\